# How to install pyinstaller on ubuntu 13?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, ubuntu-13.10

I tried:(referred pyinstaller manual)

```
pip install PyInstaller
```

but it gave error:

```
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller': Permission denied

----------------------------------------

Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-pratik/pyinstaller/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wrGEjP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-pratik/pyinstaller

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 139, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 271, in run
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1185, in install
requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 592, in install
cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 662, in call_subprocess
% (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-pratik/pyinstaller/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wrGEjP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-pratik/pyinstaller
```

I have taken this from pip.log

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this with `sudo` privileges.

You're getting a permission denied error in the line:

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo pip install PyInstaller
```

The permissions issue is saying that you don't have permissions to create the directory. `sudo` gives you the permission.

Answer (score 1):

To install without using sudo:

`pip install PyInstaller --user`